# Prolog query infinite search

Tags: prolog, stack-overflow, nfa

I am a beginner to Prolog and I would like to ask a question about Prolog.

My program is based on non-deterministic finite-state automaton.

the start state is **S0** and the final state is **S3**.

The diagram is

[image]

so if there is a string `[a,a,b,b,c,c]` it should be like

```
start(s0).
edge(a, s0, s0).
edge(a, s0, s1).
edge(b, s1, s1).
edge(b, s1, s2).
edge(c, s2, s2).
edge(c, s2, s3).
final(s3).
```

There is a predicate `accepts(Ls)` if (there `Ls` is a list of string)

```
accepts(Ls) :- start(A), goesTo(Ls, A, B), final(B).
```

and assuming that the NFA goes from state **Si** to state **Sj** and in between them there is a state **Sk**, `goesTo` predicate is defined as

```
goesTo(Ls, Si, Sj) :- edge (L, Si, Sk), goesTo(Ls, Sk, Sj).
```

But if querying `accepts(Ls)` (any arbitrary list of string ranging from `a` to `c`)
the tutorial question says that it will almost certainly go into an infinite search and stack overflow will occur.

However, I don't understand why the query will go into an infinite search and cause stack overflow. If you can give me the reason, it would be really great!

***(edit:)*** the exact quote is:

> "a typical Prolog user might hope that his/her goesTo rules would be such tat the query accepts(X) would generate successive strings that are accepted by the NFA above. Almost certainly, given the above presentation of the given NFA, the Prolog system will go into an infinite search and stack overflow will occur. Say why this is so. (if your goesTo avoid this problem, say how you managed to avoid it)."

Comment: your *program* is based on N-D F-S *automaton*. Right?

Answer (score 2):

This is the definition of your NFA:

```
start(s0). 
edge(a, s0, s0). 
edge(a, s0, s1). 
edge(b, s1, s1). 
edge(b, s1, s2).
edge(c, s2, s2). 
edge(c, s2, s3).
final(s3).
```

It has no connection to any input string you might test for acceptance by it. Note the dots at the end of each line - these are Prolog predicates that define the NFA.

Running your `accepts/1` with *any* **concrete** input string will result in finite recursion. The search space here is finite, and it will certainly be exhausted - provided you call `accepts/1` with fully instantiated string of finite length.

Now, if you were to try to **generate** all the possible <s>paths</s> acceptable strings, then you'd have an infinite recursion because there are infinite number of acceptable strings:

```
a,b,c
a,a,b,c
a,a,a,b,c
a,a,a,a,b,c
.....
```

are all strings acceptable by this automaton.

Your predicate definitions all miss the final dot BTW. And `goesTo` is not quite right. It must be changed to:

```
goesTo([], S, S).
goesTo([L1|Ls], S1, Sn) :- edge(L1, S1, S2), goesTo(Ls, S2, Sn).
accepts(Ls) :- start(A), goesTo(Ls, A, B), final(B).
```

Also note, there must be no space between the predicate name and the opening parenthesis.

---

So now the OP have clarified their question. It is,

> *why an attempt to generate all possible acceptable strings will almost certainly go into an unproductive loop*?

The call `accepts(X)` indeed goes into infinite recursion, because generation of a new node to try is restarted from the beginning, and so internally, an infinitely growing string of `a`s is tried:

```
a
a,a
a,a,a
a,a,a,a
....
```

simply because `edge(a,s0,s0)` is the very first `edge` fact in the database, and the call to `edge/3` is in the first position inside `goesTo/3` predicate definition. And Prolog's search strategy is left-to-right.

We can get from totally unproductive behaviour (where Prolog just hangs in an infinite loop) to a productive behaviour by rearranging the goals like so:

```
start(s0). 
edge(a, s0, s1). 
edge(b, s1, s2).
edge(c, s2, s3).
edge(a, s0, s0). 
edge(b, s1, s1). 
edge(c, s2, s2). 
final(s3).
```

Now,

```
12 ?- accepts(X).

X = [a, b, c] ;
X = [a, b, c, c] ;
X = [a, b, c, c, c] ;
X = [a, b, c, c, c, c] ;
X = [a, b, c, c, c, c, c] ;
X = [a, b, c, c, c, c, c, c] ;
X = [a, b, c, c, c, c, c, c, c]
```

Unfortunately as can be seen the generation is skewed towards `c`. How to make it "fair"... let's leave it to another question, shall we?

Comment: `accepts(X).` goes into loop. Maybe that's what they meant - the generation, not the testing. Or it is simply an error.

Comment: ahh, now you showing us the exact quote! :) That totally makes sense: generation goes into loop indeed. I suggest you add this quote into your question body, and I'll edit my answer in the meantime.

Comment: I've changed the var names to less suggestive. The var name is totally local to a predicate definition. It can be anything. Using same name twice means the two are the same: `goesTo([],S,S).` is the same as `goesTo([],X,Y):- X=Y.`.

Comment: but I think that Sj Sj would be suit this scenario

Comment: I do understand your answer but I still don't understand why stack overflow occur here because from my understanding at least, stack overflow occurs when you set the maximum number of things you can put inside the stack and when the maximum number reaches then stack overflow occurs.

Comment: hmm... looks like `goesTo` *is* tail-recursive *modulo-cons*... so perhaps no stack is growing at all, just the internal list (a,  a,a  a,a,a  a,a,a,a,  ...) - which will eventually use up all available memory... but no stack overflow! But on implementations without the tail-recursion-modulo-cons properly implemented, the stack will grow when `goesTo` calls `edge` and then `goesTo` again - and is stack grows it'll be exhausted at some time - causing *"overflow"*.

Answer (score 1):

The program will loop because of the search strategy adopted by Prolog. It tries to solve a query exploring the solution space with a *[depth first](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)* strategy, that is space efficient but incomplete.

Now should be clear that the solution space *is* infinite in your case, because of these loops in the graph. There are infinite paths from initial to final state.

[Iterative deepening](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening) should be the simpler way to enumerate the paths, it's easy to implement in Prolog. Another possibility would be implementing a *[breadth first](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)* search.

Answer (score 1):

Because it's loops as stated by others.

p.s the assignment has been extended to this thursday, so no need to panic [yet]
 and yeah, I know what assignment you're doing